# How to find the method that called a specific method?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I am looking for a way to find which method called a specific method that I am currently in.

For example, I am looking at `create()` method of `account.move.line` model.

```
@api.model_create_multi
def create(self, vals_list):
    res = super(AccountMoveLine, self.with_context(context)).create(vals_list)
    return res
```

When this method is executed, I would like to find which method called it at runtime.

Comment: Debugging? Using [traceback](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html)?

Comment: @CZoellner That is a very useful library! I will try it out.

Comment: The question would be more specific if you add what you want to do with this information. Because without that information you probably get cheeky comments like mine: "Debugging?" ;-) But `traceback` was no cheeky comment. I've used it for logging a traceback elsewhere in try-excepts in situations where Odoo should not rollback everything, but just could go on.

Comment: @CZoellner I agree. I will create a new question for that. Just leave this question be like this, which I think it is okay.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way is to create a new Automated Action (in debug mode under the Technical menu) and just type any random python code so that it bombs out. When creating a new `account.move.line` the traceback is on the screen.